# react native FlatList horizontal scroll is not smooth

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to implement a Flat in horizontal direction. It contains small cards contains some data. At a time 2 and half card are visible horizontally, when i scroll it directly goes to next 3 cards so I am not able to properly view the third card since scroll moves 3 items at once.

How I can make freely scroll able so user can stop it at any card anywhere ?

Comment: could you please add code of your flatlist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

```
pagingEnabled={false}
```

to the flatlist.